# Weird behaviour in for-loop in C++ on Mac

Tags: c++, macos

I have the following function:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Surfel>> testAddingSift(
        const Groundtruth &groundtruth, 
        SurfelHelper &surfelHelper) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
        std::cout << "hej" << k <<std::endl;
    }
}
```

When I forgot to return a `vector<vector<Surfel>>` I got an infinite loop:

```
 hej1025849
 hej1025850
 hej1025851
 hej1025852
```

When I return a `vector<vector<Surfel>>` I get:

```
hej0
hej1
hej2
hej3
hej4
hej5
hej6
hej7 
hej8
hej9
```

Of course it was a mistake to forget to return the vector, but why is the for-loop affected?

I am using a MacBook Pro with Sierra and CLion and I think it is clang.

Comment: Undefined behavior works in mysterious ways.

Comment: Your loop should print `"hej"` ten times, with no digits following the string. Did you copy your loop correctly?

Comment: Undefined behavior can to _anything_

Comment: I just changed the printout when I was writing the question to make it clearer. Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Failure to return from a function with non-void return type is [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Doing so makes it, by definition, nearly impossible to reason about the resulting behavior. This can affect the behavior of code that comes before the point where undefined behavior would be expected to be encountered.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I have never seen that before so I was a bit confused. I mean it is not the first time I forget to return something, but that has never caused this kind of problems before.

Comment: @El_Loco One of the worst things about undefined behavior is that sometimes it looks like it works. Undefined behavior can result in any behavior, including the behavior you expected. It goes undetected for a while and can suddenly stop working at any time for no apparent reason. This can even lead you to believe that something is valid c++ when it's not.

Comment: The compiler is free to assume undefined behavior never occurs. One possibility is that the compiler assumed that execution would never reach the end of the function because that would cause undefined behavior, which is assumed to never happen. If the condition of the `for` loop is ever false, then the end of the function would be reached, so it can also assume that the condition is simply always true. It's then allowed to optimize the comparison out of the loop, resulting in an infinite loop. But this is *just one possibility*. There may be many more.

Answer (score 1):

The proper answer here is that this is, of course, undefined behavior, so anything could happen. A more interesting question is, how in the world would something silly, like forgetting a return statement, lead to an infinite loop?

> It is not the first time I forget to return something, but that has never caused this kind of problems before.

My best guess is that the result that you see has to do with returning an object by value when the object has a non-trivial copy constructor. In your case, copy constructor is rather non-trivial, because it needs to deal with nested arrays. In particular, I suspect that the infinite loop would go away if you change return type to an `int` (the behavior would remain undefined, though).

My guess is that when your loop calls `operator <<` it places return address on the stack. Once `operator <<` returns, the stack frame becomes unused, but its content remains intact. I suspect that the code for copying the returned vector re-interprets the content of the "garbage" stack frame as a vector with lots of elements, and invokes loop's body instead of copying array elements.

This is just one possibility. If you would like to find out what is happening, the proper way would be to dig through the disassembly.